# Utilizing existing light switch for new GFCI outlet

Tags: wiring

We are updating our master bathroom. Currently, we have a GFCI outlet which we are not going to change and a double light switch which controls a ceiling light and a light bar on the wall above the mirror.  We will no longer use the light bar above the mirror but only the ceiling fixture. That will free up a light switch which we like to use for a second GFCI outlet. Is this possible to do. If so, what would the wiring scheme look like?

We looked at GFCI outlets today and noticed that they have 2 silver screws and 2 brass screws for wires....do we use all four screws?

Many thanks to all.

Comment: Do you mean "connect up a GFCI outlet to the switch, so that the switch turns the outlet on and off" or do you mean "use the physical location that currently has a switch to install a GFCI outlet in place of that switch"? They are both possible (depending...) but are very different questions.

Comment: This sort of question calls for photos or a sketch of the existing wiring. We don't have enough to work with.

Comment: No, you only use the LINE screws on a GFCI unless you know exactly what you are doing (i.e. know a LOT more than how to put a wire on the screw).  Are all these switches and outlets next to each other in the same box?  Are they on the same circuit?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?